Including random effect reduces model fit
I am fitting a zero-inflated negative binomial GLMM to model counts. Fixed effects are all categorical except Effort_sq which are non-zero values. The experiment is performed several times within a trip and several trips are carried out (>6 levels so I include it as random effect).

shark_zi <- glmmTMB(sharks ~ Treatment+ Net_type + Effort_sq + (1|Trip_code), ziformula = ~., family="nbinom1", data=P1)

I use the DHARMa package to perform diagnostics and it shows that the quantile test is significant:
simulateResiduals(fittedModel = shark_zi, plot = T)
summary(shark_zi)



However if I try a GLM instead, the test is not significant:
shark_zi_2 <- glmmTMB(sharks ~ Treatment+ Net_type + Effort_sq, ziformula = ~., family="nbinom1", data=P1)

simulateResiduals(fittedModel = shark_zi_2, plot = T)



I compare the two models as in Bolker GLMM FAQs
anova(shark_zi, shark_zi_2)


To explore the issue I also added Trip_Code as a fixed effect to the same model, but I have the following error:
dropping columns from rank-deficient conditional model: Trip_code27
dropping columns from rank-deficient zero-inflation model: Trip_code27
Warning message:
In finalizeTMB(TMBStruc, obj, fit, h, data.tmb.old) :
Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
How do I interpret these results and what else should I consider in order to improve fit? I have no other variables to include as random effect andI have performed model selection using 'dredge' but the reduced model resulting from it also has a bad fit.
Also, would it be pseudoreplication to exclude the random effect? According to Hurlbert (1984) "Consider not testing the significance of random effects. If the random effect is part of the experimental design, this procedure may be considered ‘sacrificial pseudoreplication’
Thanks!
Update
As suggested in the comments I have simplified the model because the model summary showed high standard errors (specifically for Effort_sq). I used Effort (non squared values) instead, ziformula=~1 and used 'dredge' to select terms. The models now compared are:
shark_zi <- glmmTMB(sharks ~ Net_type + (1|Trip_code), ziformula = ~1, family="nbinom1", data=P1)
simulateResiduals(fittedModel = shark_zi, plot = T)


shark_zi_2 <- glmmTMB(sharks ~ Net_type, ziformula = ~1, family="nbinom1", data=P1)
simulateResiduals(fittedModel = shark_zi_2, plot = T)


The same question remains on why the addition of random effects would cause issues in terms of homogeneity of variance.
Is the fact that superficial nets were used in more than >80% of fishing sets something relevant?

That's interesting. I haven't come across a scenario where including a random effect makes the model worse. I have nothing useful to offer, but commenting so I can follow this thread :)

What happens if you include trip as a fixed effect? I'm guessing this doesn't stem from the fact that it is a random effect per se, but rather that this variable is omitted. Could you share your data?

@sjp I have just tried and model doesn't converge (see edited post). Unfortunately I cannot share my data for now (sorry to be unhelpful!), would providing the model summary be useful? Or anything else that I can show that is not the full dataset?

I don't get it. It looks to me like the model with the random effect has more support (lower AIC/BIC). What am I missing?

Also, even if it did make the model worse, I'd still include it if you had theoretical reason to (i.e. if the points are not independent).

@mkt the AIC is lower for the random effect model, but the model fit doesn't look good (see plot on the right with red lines). Would you still include the random effect and ignore the bad  residual plot?

Ah, I see your point. I would still include hierarchical structure based on the experimental design, but you could consider whether including a random slope term would be theoretically justifiable. If so, try adding that and checking the diagnostic plot.

Is it possible to share a head of your data, so we can understand the predictors a bit more? And maybe a summary of the two models

@AlexJ I have edited to include the info

Thanks @AlessandraBielli. I think your model has too many parameters for your data. For example, Effort_sq has a coefficient of 13 and standard error of 8, which is MASSIVE. And same for the zero-inflation component - you're trying to fit three zero-inflation predictors, and you can see the errors on them are massive. I think you need to really simplify this model to get useful results out of it. Try ~ 1 for the zero-inflated part, unless you have a strong theoretical reason why you need a predictor for it.

From your design, I think the trip as a random effect sounds theoretically correct though

Thanks @AlexJ, I agree that the model should be simplified, and also agree that including trip as random effect is theoretically  correct, but is it acceptable to keep the random effect and ignore the significant Levene test? also, the question remains the same about why the random effect is causing issues with diagnostics plots (see edited post).

Hmmm. I am not sure. I certainly agree that the random effects model looks worse than the standard GLM

Could you add a bit to the question body describing the study methods, and what each variable means?

Is there any chance of a reproducible example?
